# how to create line plots on scatterplot - from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I have a dataframe of the Titanic survivers. the columns are:

```
Age, Pclass(1,2,3), Fare, Passenger_id, Sex
```

and I did a scatterplot of Age vs. Fare for all passengers, separating both the classes (using colors) and gender (using different symbols/markers) like that:

```
for index, row in Data_Frame.iterrows():
    plt.scatter(x=row['Age'], y=row['Fare'], marker='.' if row['Sex'] == 'male' else 'D', c= 'g' if row['Pclass']==1 else 'r' if row['Pclass']==2 else 'b')
```

Now, I have a question: I want to add two line plots on the same graph,  one showing the average age for each class, and the other showing the average fare for each class. 
Classes are on the x-axis. Use different line styles and colors, and include a legend. 
Try to set legend location in a manner that does not interfere with the other elements in the graph.

how do I do that? how can I draw two line plots easily?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Write the two plots below the previous plot, by default mtplotlib will superimpose the graphs.